# How to wrap in 2 elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I want to make the following code:

```
<h2>TEXTz</h2>
<p>ARTICLE</p>


<h2>TEXTx</h2>
<p>ARTICLE</p>
```

Look like this:

```
<div class="highlight">
<h2>TEXTz</h2>
<p>ARTICLE</p>
</div>

<h2>TEXTx</h2>
<p>ARTICLE</p>
```

But I have to use: contains for find h2 text and add wrap before `h2` and after `p`.

My failed code:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{containsExact: function(a,i,m){return $.trim(a.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) === m[3].toLowerCase();}});

var byItem = "TEXTz"

var ItemTitle = $("h2:containsExact(" + byItem +")").text();
var ItemDes = $("h2:containsExact(" + byItem +")").next("p").text();

$("h2:containsExact(" + byItem +")").html('<section class="highlightitem"><h2>' + ItemTitle + '</h2><p>' + ItemDes + '</p></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NDUzW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) allows adding elements to a jquery object.

Then you can use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrape a set of elements in jQuery.

```
var $h2 = $("h2:containsExact(" + byItem +")");
if ($h2.length) {
    $h2.add( $h2.next('p') )
       .wrapAll( $('<div>').addClass('highlight') );
}
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/9YCt3/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the jQuery functions:

```
var byItem = "TEXTz"

    $("h2")
        .filter(
            function() {
                if ($(this).html() == byItem) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
           }
       )
       .next("p")
       .andSelf()
       .wrapAll($("<section>")
            .addClass("highlightitem")
       );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NDUzW/1/)